# Mongo is letting me down

Tags: mongodb, shell, command-line

I've been trying to run mongo on my system, but I just doesn't want to start. I've installed mongodb with brew. Both mongo and mongod are on my system and I can use them. But the mongod process won't start.

These are the steps I'm taking after I installed mongo on my system with brew.

```
$ mongod
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
$
```

It seems mongod is closing directly, because I don't see any process running and it gives me the dollar sign back again. Thereby there's no rotating icon in my terminal, so it isn't running.

If I open a new window in the terminal after running the above command, I'm getting this error:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
connecting to: test
Thu May 23 12:22:09.314 JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112
exception: connect failed
$
```

This output is a logical error seen from the fact mongod didn't do a thing. But when I run this:

```
$ ps -ef | grep mongod
  501 99123 15827   0 12:24PM ttys001    0:00.00 grep mongod
$
```

So I'm not sure or it's running or not.. You guys know a solution for this? Because I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong..

**update**

I've tried to change the db path and that works partially. I'm now able to run mongod command, but I need to specify the dbPath even though I have the dbPath changed in the config file.

```
$ mongod --dbpath ~/data/db/
```

And when I try to run mongod by itself, it won't run..

```
$ mongod
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
$
```

Comment: What does it say in: `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log` ?

Comment: Paste the out put of mongo.log

Comment: @Sammaye: Found the solution. Tried to point to /data/db and ~/data/db but both ways didn't work. Found that I had to set the path to /Users/name/data/db/ to make it work.. Thanks for pointing out to look to the log file.

Comment: Yeah you cannot use `~` and stuff like that within MongoDBs configuration

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a working solution, but from your output, it seems like mongod is running daemonized. You could try setting the 'fork' option to false (or uncommenting it) in **/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.x-x86_64/mongod.conf** and running mongod with the -v / --verbose flag to see if that gives you more details.

Also, are you sure you're actually using the homebrew version of mongo and not some previously installed version? You can check which mongod is used by running:

```
➜  ~  which mongod
/usr/local/bin/mongod
```

And the following to see if that's indeed the version that got installed using homebrew:

```
➜  ~  ls -l /usr/local/bin/mongod
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin  41 21 mrt 22:06 /usr/local/bin/mongod -> ../Cellar/mongodb/2.4.x-x86_64/bin/mongod
```

Comment: Everything was installed correctly. Found out that I had to point to:  /Users/name/data/db/ instead of ~/data/db or /data/db. Strange thing was that I could navigate to the ~/data/db folder..

Answer (score 0):

The default data directory is `/data/db`. In order to have that work by default you need to do two things:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
sudo chown `whoami` /data/db
```